# Removing specific text from each line

Tags: java, string

I have about thousand lines of the type:

```
<option value="1436">Some text
<option value="36">Some text
```

I want to store a fresh file, without `<...>` part in it.
The code I'm writing is:

```
try{
    FileInputStream fs= new FileInputStream(f);
    Scanner s= new Scanner(fs);
    while (s.hasNext()){
        String sentence=s.nextLine();
        int l=sentence.length();
        try{//printing P
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Ps.txt"));
            for (int i=0;i<l;i++){
                if (sentence.charAt(i)=='>'){
                    for (int j=i+1;j<l;j++)
                    bw.write(sentence.charAt(j));
                }
                bw.newLine();
            }
            bw.close();
        }   
        catch(Exception e){}
    }
}
```

However, it just storing 3-4 lines in the output file.

Comment: Does the Some text have > and < in them? Otherwise would sed work - sed -e 's/[<|\]//g' file1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are opening and closing the file inside your while loop.you'll want to move it outside of the main loop, so you open the file once  don't close the file until the end.

Thus, every iteration of the loop, you are overwriting the file, so the contents of the file will only be what was computed by the last iteration of the loop.

Comment: Yes, I figure that out. Used `FileOutputStream ffs = new FileOutputStream ("ps.txt",true);`

Comment: That will work, but its not the most efficient.  You are better off just moving the new BufferedWriter(...) before the start of the while loop, and the bw.close() after the end of the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

If using sed is an option, then

`cat file1 | sed 's/\<.*\>//' > file2`

Should do the trick